# Increment int each time the termination expression is checked in a for loop

Tags: java, algorithm

Is it possible to increment something each time the for loop checks the termination condition? I'm trying to compare two sort algorithms for a project, and I have a increment for the number of swaps made, but I'd also like to increment something for each time it checks the termination condition on the for loop. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
    for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
        for (int j=i; (j>0) && (array[j]<(array[j-1])); j--) {
            Sort.swap(array, j, j-1);
            swaps++;
        }
    }
```

As said, I would like to check how many times "(j>0) && (array[j]<(array[j-1]))" is evaluated so that I may compare it to other sorting algorithms.

I've tried adding increments in the loop but it gives me errors for adding increments in the termination expression, stating that they cannot be converted to bool.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: number of "termination checks" is the number of the iterations + 1 , so just intialiaze a counter to 1 and increment it on the beginning of each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last clause of a `for` expression is evaluated every iteration. You can put more than one variable increment in that space.

```
for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
    int checks = 1; // There is always one more check than iterations, the last check being the one which ends the iteration
    for (int j=i; (j>0) && (array[j]<(array[j-1])); j--, checks++) {
        Sort.swap(array, j, j-1);
        swaps++;
    }
    System.out.println(checks);
}
```

Comment: You should mention that `checks` should be initialized by `1`.

Comment: What in the OP's question makes you think that's important?

Comment: Hi want to count how many times `(j>0) && (array[j]<(array[j-1]))` is calculated. If you initialize `checks` to something other then `1` you get wrong answer.

Comment: Then in _your_own_ answer, you should initialise `int counter = 1`. Besides, what wrong with just doing `System.out.println(checks + 1)` ?

Comment: In my own answer initialization is correct. and there is nothing wrong with `println(checks + 1)` except you need to remember that your variable store value that is shifted by on from what all expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: >> you need to remember that your variable store value that is shifted << Array indexing and iteration is zero-based in the C / C++ / Java tradition

Comment: But counters doesn't :(

Comment: Well, the purpose of the counter was "so that I may compare it to other sorting algorithms", that's all. I will change it, but I think it is amazing hair-splitting. I'm certainly shocked to get a downvote for what is essentially a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to introduce new class `Counter`

```
class Counter {
    private int counter = 0;
    public boolean count(boolean b) {
         counter++;
         return b;
    }
    public int getCount() {
         return count;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Counter c = new Counter();
for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (int j=i; c.count((j>0) && (array[j]<(array[j-1]))); j--) {
        Sort.swap(array, j, j-1);
        swaps++;
    }
}
System.out.println(c.getCount());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!